# How to set number of lines for an QTextEdit?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qtextedit

I use a QTextEdit for some inputs. But I want to adjust the height of the box. Can I set the height based on the number of lines I want to have visible at a time?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you use `QPlainTextEdit`, something like this should do the trick:

```
void SetHeight (QPlainTextEdit* edit, int nRows)
  {
  QFontMetrics m (edit -> font()) ;
  int RowHeight = m.lineSpacing() ;
  edit -> setFixedHeight  (nRows * RowHeight) ;
  }
```

You might want to add two or three pixels as margin; experiment will tell.

Comment: This ignores the margin and border of the widget so the last line is cut of. The amount of pixels to add depends on the theme in use so it's more complex than this.

Answer (score 11):

Improving the accepted answer about `QPlainTextEdit`. In addition to `lineSpacing`, value for `setFixedHeight` should contain: 2 margins of the underlying `QTextDocument`, 2 widths of the frame and widget's contents margins. Besides that, `QFontMetrics` must be got from a font of the document, not of the widget itself. So, hypothetical function `setHeight` should read as follows:

```
void setHeight (QPlainTextEdit *ptxt, int nRows)
{
    QTextDocument *pdoc = ptxt->document ();
    QFontMetrics fm (pdoc->defaultFont ());
    QMargins margins = ptxt->contentsMargins ();
    int nHeight = fm.lineSpacing () * nRows +
        (pdoc->documentMargin () + ptxt->frameWidth ()) * 2 +
        margins.top () + margins.bottom ();
    ptxt->setFixedHeight (nHeight);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `QFont` to determine the height of a single line of text in the `QTextEdit` (QTextEdit should have a *font* property). After that multiply the `QFont`'s *height* value with the number of lines you want to show and set the widget's (minimum-)height to that value.

Comment: The trouble with QTextEdit is that each line can have a different height. If you only need a single text format (but with different colours allowed), maybe QPlainTextEdit is better.

Answer (score 1):

QTextEdit is a normal widget, so you can use [minimumHeight](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qwidget.html#minimumHeight-prop) property. I believe, however, that it is really impossible to set minimum height based on number of lines. This would resize automagically the minimum size of a widget every time you change size of the font. But if you know the size of the font, you can set some usable minimum size of your widget.

Comment: QTextEdit has mouse wheel zoom enabled by default, so you would need to turn this off.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
QTextEdit *myEdit = new QTextEdit(myContentString);
QSize myEditSize = myEdit->document()->size().toSize();
myEditSize.setWidth(QWIDGETSIZE_MAX);
myEdit->setMaximumSize(myEditSize);
```