# QPlainTextEdit - absolute size

Tags: c++, qt, qplaintextedit

I need to get absolute height of the `QPlainTextEdit`, as if it's not in `QAbstractScrollArea`. I've already spent about an hour finding it out. I've searched `QPlainTextEdit`, `QTextDocument` and `QAbstractScrollArea`, tried every property with size in it's name.

I hope there's other way than to multiply the `blockCount()` by `blockBoundingRect(firstVisibleBlock()).height()` and add to content offset. (Blocks are the same size.)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258665/how-to-set-number-of-lines-for-an-qtextedit

Comment: @user2672165 I'll check it out. My formula works as well so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this in your derived class:

```
int TextEditor::contentHeight() const
{
    return contentOffset().y() + fontMetrics().lineSpacing() * blockCount();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for: http://qt-project.org/forums/viewreply/21633/

The `QScrollArea` has a Viewport. The Viewport is the size of the viewable area. So if your `QScrollArea` is named `foo`, you'll want to do this:

```
 foo.viewport().size();
```

Which will return you your desired `QSize`.

Comment: I don't want viewable, I want absolute - out of the bounds of the viewport.

Comment: @LogicStuff That should be maintained in your original object. So if your `QPlainTextEdit` is named `bar` you should just be able to do: `bar.size();`

Comment: That's the same (plus height of horizontal scroll bar I suppose).

Comment: @LogicStuff Seems like we're having a miscomunication, Viewport + scroll bars = `QScrollArea.size()`. `bar.size()` is different from the Viewport and the `QScrollArea.size()`... unless you've just gotten really lucky/unlucky with your widget's size.

Comment: I think the OP is asking how to get "how tall would the widget need to be to display all of the content without scrolling vertically" - not the current widget size.

Comment: Simply, assume `textEdit` has `100` lines of text, but viewport can display only `50`. If height of one line is `15`px, I want to be getting ~`1500`, not `750`.

Comment: @Andrew Medico Exactly.